# Converting from .dat to netcdf(.nc)

Tags: ascii, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a `.dat file` https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dbjg0i6l7a4sb6/CRUST10-xyz-complete.dat?dl=0 that I need to convert to either `.grd` or `.nc`, so that I can visualize the data in `GMT(Generic Mapping Tool)`. I tried to do this using `cdo` using following command:

```
cdo -f nc import_binary  CRUST10-xyz-complete.dat CRUST10-xyz-complete.nc
```

but got following error:

```
Open Error:  Unknown keyword in description file
  --> The invalid description file record is: 
  --> 0.5,89.5,4.19,0,2,0.7,0,0.73,1.62,5.01,14.25,10.06,7.36,2.7,1.5,3.81,2,3.5,0,5,6.5,7.1,8.07,5.5865805168986,6.7596467391304,2.3888888888889
  The data file was not opened. 

cdo import_binary (Abort): Open failed!
```

Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 1):

First make `.ctl` file then apply:-

```
cdo -f nc import_binary  CRUST10-xyz-complete.ctl CRUST10-xyz-complete.nc
```

Here is the example link for to make `.ctl` file. http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/descriptorfile.html

It will definitely work for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without the data itself, it is hard to see what went wrong. In any case, just look at the following message from cdo forum:
https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/3631

which you could use as an example of how to convert ASCII data to netCDF using cdo's.

Comment: Question edited. Follow the dropbox link to view the .dat file

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Bart, I cannot take credit of others work or just duplicate, when there is a really good example available with Python scripts etc. at cdo webpage... Sometimes it is better to think twice before making an action.

Comment: I partially understand, but believe that copying the relevant part (of course, mentioning the source) is not a problem. Tomorrow (or next week, month, year, ..) that weblink will be dead, and your answer is no longer an answer :-)